# .htaccess add exception to disabled CGI execution

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver

I have a website with a "protected folder" using a .htaccess file.
Inside this folder the execution of CGIs is disabled, the .htaccess is as follow

```
Options -Indexes -Includes -ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi .php4 .php5 .js
```

Now I'm in the need of executing a PHP script in this folder (overiding the CGI disabling), lets suposse the name of my script is

```
my_script.php
```

What is the best way to maintain my security in this folder deniying the execution rights to ALL the scripts BUT to **my_script.php**?

I have full access to the .htaccess file so I can change what I want.
Kind regards and thanks a lot in advance.
P:.

Comment: Are you sure you need the ExecCGI flag? Are you running PHP as CGI? It's more common to run PHP with mod_php or using something like suPHP, neither of which require the ExecCGI flag.